# Finding max value by Row and displaying its column name correspodingly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array , which consists of 4 columns and 2 rows. I wish to find the maximum value in the second row and return the corresponding value name . In other words my output should be :521 (100 has the 99 value aswell but i need to return the first value ).

ive tried this : (student_ids is the first row , and grades is the lower one (average of some grades array ) . the following function returned me the 624 value .

```
def find_student_with_max_avg(grades, student_ids):
    return np.max(np.vstack((student_ids, np.mean(grades, axis=0))))
```

array :
[[521 597 624 100]
 [ 99  73  97  99]]

Keep in mind that the solution should be simple , around one line as we are not allowed to use loops and its around basic numpy methods . no imports other than numpy aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Input:

```
array : [[521 597 624 100] [ 99 73 97 99]]
```

First, find the index of `max` in second row like this,

```
idx = np.argmax(arr[1])
```

Then, extract the element from first row of that index,

```
print(arr[0][idx])
```

Output:

```
521
```

Comment: @bertington313 you can do it one line as well. I just did it in two lines for the sake of clarity and understanding. Hope you understand.